# Change version of R in Jupyter

Tags: r, installation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, updates

I have tried uninstalling R and reinstalling a more up to date version. Currently I have R 4.0.3 installed and yet when I run R in Jupyter and check the version it is running R 3.6.1

I have removed R from the Jupyter Kernel and reinstalled and this has not worked, does anyone know how I can change the version of R that is run in Jupyter?

Comment: It depends on which R kernel do you use, but assuming that you use IRkernel you need to install specs for for the other R version as described in the [installation](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel#installation) section of the readme. Please confirm if running `IRkernel::installspec` with appropriate arguments it worked for you.

Comment: Hi that was the issue, I installed using the anaconda prompt and hadn't specifies the version. Thanks so much I could have been all day figuring that out